# Xcode: How to add custom fonts in module for project.xcodeproj

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to add a custom font to my project in Xcode. But it does not record the source. I already tried that option and it didn't work.
How do I add the font in a module to be used in the main app?

I try this

```swift
static func registerFontWithFilenameString(filenameString: String, bundleIdentifierString: String) {
        let frameworkBundle = NSBundle(forClass: AnyClassInYourFramework.self)
        let resourceBundleURL = frameworkBundle.URLForResource(bundleIdentifierString, withExtension: "bundle")
        if let bundle = NSBundle(URL: resourceBundleURL!) {
            let pathForResourceString = bundle.pathForResource(filenameString, ofType: nil)
            let fontData = NSData(contentsOfFile: pathForResourceString!)
            let dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(fontData)
            let fontRef = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(dataProvider)
            var errorRef: Unmanaged<CFError>? = nil

            if (CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(fontRef!, &errorRef) == false) {
                NSLog("Failed to register font - register graphics font failed - this font may have already been registered in the main bundle.")
            }
        }
        else {
            NSLog("Failed to register font - bundle identifier invalid.")
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app